# How to use the facet grid or facet wrap method in ggplot2 with stacked bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set with four variables, say: category, date, var1, value1. The data frame looks like:

```
date       category   var1   value1  
2000-01-01  A          V1     22
2000-01-01  A          V2     21
2000-01-01  B          V1     31
2000-01-01  C          V1     23
2000-01-01  D          V2     45
2000-01-02  A          V2     35
2000-01-02  B          V1     56
2000-01-02  B          V2     17 
2000-01-02  C          V1     27
2000-01-02  D          V2     89
```

Now I need to plot the data with ggplot2 facet grid/wrap in the following format:
1) X-axis is date, Y-axis is value1.
2) Stacked bar plot with var1.
3) A 2*2 facet by category, to be specific, I have four values of the category.

What I coded as below, but error returned:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value1, fill=var1))  
g + geom_bar(stat="identity") +    
  + facet_grid(.~category, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

Error:

> "invalid argument to unary operator"

How can I fix this error and get the graph I want as described above?
Also what is the difference between facet_grid and facet_wrap in this case, which one should I use?

I appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: You have two `+`'s between `geom_bar` and `facet_grid`, remove one of them?

Comment: Yeah. I removed the extra + and tried again, but got only one stacked bar plot filled with var1, without facet grid by category. And the same error occurred. Seems that the first statement "ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value1, fill=var1)) " was executed while the last one about facet grid was not.

Comment: You have to end each line with the `+` if you're going to put your calls on separate lines, otherwise R doesn't know that the expression is unfinished and won't continue on to the next line.

Comment: Adjusted my code and finally got what I expected! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used facet_grid while facet_wrap did not work......

Comment: It should be `facet_wrap( ~ category, ...)` or `facet_grid( . ~ category, ...)`. Note the additional "dot".

Comment: Yeah, this time facet_wrap worked, with my current R version, facet_grid(~category,) returned the graph. Thank you very much!